# What is the best way to sort by columns in mysql and use index?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have a table with 10 columns, Now I want to give the users an option to sort the data with any column they want. For example suppose a combo box with 7 items that each of them is a column of the table, now the user choose one item and get the data sorted by the chosen column.

**Now what is the problem?**

My table has 3M records, and if I sort the data with indexed column I have no problem but with a non index column it takes 3.5mins to sort!!!

**What is the solution I am thinking about?**

Add index to every column of table that is needed to be sort by! In my case I will have index on 8 columns!!!!

**What is the problem of my solution?**

Having a lot of index on columns may decrease the speed of INSERT/UPDATE queries! In my case the table is updated frequently (every second!!!!!)

What is your solution for this case?!

Comment: So "only sort on indexes" and "only index what needs to be sorted fast" -- what am I missing? While indices *can* slow down inserts/updates, first make sure this is *really a problem* here ..

Answer (score 0):

Read this for more details on optimization: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the `ORDER BY`, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the `WHERE` clause. Using index for sorting often comes together with using index to find rows, however it can also be used just for sort for example if you’re just using `ORDER BY` without and where clauses on the table. In such case you would see “Index” type in `EXPLAIN` which correspond to scanning (potentially) complete table in the index order. It is very important to understand in which conditions index can be used to sort data together with restricting amount of rows.

Looking at the same index **(A,B)**  things like `ORDER BY A ; ORDER BY A,B ;  ORDER BY A DESC, B DESC` will be able to use full index for sorting (note MySQL may not select to use index for sort if you sort full table without a limit). However `ORDER BY B` or `ORDER BY A, B DESC`  will not be able to use index because requested order does not line up with the order of data in BTREE. If you have both restriction and sorting things like this would work `A=5 ORDER BY B ; A=5 ORDER BY B DESC; A>5 ORDER BY A ; A>5 ORDER BY A,B ; A>5 ORDER BY A DESC` which again can be easily visualized as scanning a range in BTREE. Things like this however would not work `A>5 ORDER BY B , A>5 ORDER BY A,B DESC or A IN (3,4) ORDER BY B` – in these cases getting data in sorting form would require a bit more than simple range scan in the BTREE and MySQL decides to pass it on.

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1**: If you are limited to MySQL there's no better option but create 8 indexes for the possible order columns. You're insert/update are going to suffer it for sure but no real visitor will wait for 3.5 minutes for a list to be sorted.

Tune #1: To make it a little faster you can create partial indexes instead of standard indexes which will use much less space (I assume some of these columns are varchar) and this means less writes, smaller footprint in memory. You just need to check the entropy for each column with the substring and make sure you still have distinction over 90%.

For example with a query like this:

```
> select count(distinct(substring(COLUMN, 1, 5))) as part_5, count(distinct(substring(COLUMN, 1, 10))) as part_10, count(distinct(substring(COLUMN, 1, 20))) as part_20, count(distinct(COLUMN)) as sum from TABLE;
+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| part_5 | part_10 | part_20 | sum     |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| 892183 | 1996053 | 1996058 | 1996058 |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Tune #2: You can make you insert/update statements to execute in the background. The application won't be faster but the user experience is going to be much better.

Tune #3: Use bigger transactions if you can for the inserts/updates.

**Option #2**: You can try to use one of the search engines which have been built for this usage pattern (too). I would recommend [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) as I'm using it for a while with great satisfaction but I heard good about elastic search as well.